Interface Builder with different custom color assets in two targets for one shared storyboard does not update based on the target or confuses colors
I have two targets in my XCode project, Target A and Target B.
They both have an individual assets named Colors.xcassets with a color named "Background". The color "Background" in Target A is Blue, the one in Target B is Pink.
Both Targets have one shared Storyboard with two ViewController that using the color "Background". Building and Running the targets causes the interface to display the correct "Background" color for the target.
When I open the storyboard to make changes, if I have previously executed Target A and after the Target B, even in a different sequence, the storyboard displays the backgrounds with colors of both resources (blue and pink) but should display a unique background color for both ViewControllers.
Has anyone had this exact or a similar problem before?
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Report the issue with Feedback Assistant. I don't think you can do much about this.
